# ERD generator from plain text

Tags: er-diagram

I need to generate a pretty complex entity-relationship diagram, where visual design tools will not be convenient. I have many entities, some of which with up to 200 attributes.

So it would be easier to describe the database in plain text markup. Now, I did find [one tool](https://github.com/BurntSushi/erd) that seems to do it, but it's limited (you can't specify which fields relate two entities), and hasn't been updated in years.

Is there anything else available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which already has [many questions on this site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=GraphViz).

It has been around for decades, is stable and well supported, and is generally the go to tool for generating all sorts of diagrams from text. Just take a look at [the gallery](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/gallery/).

If you Google, you will find many hits on `GraphViv ERD`, here are just a few:

- [Using Graphviz dot for ERDs, network diagrams and more](http://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2015/08/20/graphviz-dot-erds-network-diagrams/)

shows how this code

```
digraph G { 
    //  
    // Defaults
    //  

    // Box for entities
    node [shape=none, margin=0]

    // One-to-many relation (from one, to many)
    edge [arrowhead=crow, arrowtail=none, dir=both]

    //  
    // Entities
    //  
    Article [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
            <tr><td bgcolor="lightblue">Article</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">id: int(11)</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">author: int(11)</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">title: varchar(255)</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">content: longtext</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">created: datetime</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">modified: datetime</td></tr>
        </table>
    >]

    Comment [label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
            <tr><td bgcolor="lightblue">Comment</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">id: int(11)</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">author: int(11)</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">content: longtext</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">created: datetime</td></tr>
            <tr><td align="left">modified: datetime</td></tr>
        </table>
    >]  

    //  
    // Relationships
    //  
    Article->Comment;
}
```

generates this diagram

[image]

There are also a ton of options, if you have preferences.

---

You said of the previous tool which you found

> it's limited (you can't specify which fields relate two entities)

[This page](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/11/15/table-rel-diagrams-graphviz/) shows a diagram which was created with GraphViz and does just that. It's SVG, so I can't embed it here, but you can see it on that page or as a standalone image [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/wp-content/uploads/20170927114013/out.svg)

The author also explains how he generated it. He also links to a great [MS Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EFanZh.graphviz-preview) which shows you a live preview of the diagram as you code it.

---

And, finally, here's [a GitHub project](Translates a plain text description of a relational database schema to a graphical entity-relationship diagram.) which

> Translates a plain text description of a relational database schema to a graphical entity-relationship diagram.

I am sure that you are answer is in there somewhere, and that will find many imaginative uses for GraphViz :-)

Comment: OK, thanks. I did know graphviz, but it's markup language is quite complex and was hoping for something simpler (ERD uses graphviz as its engine, but with a much simpler markup). I guess it will be worth investigating creating a small python script to generate the graphviz markup.

Comment: Lol! One man's "complex" is another man's "powerful". I never thought of it as complex, but YMMV. Possibly that's because I do what you are contemplating, and generate it. Give it a try and let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) software? I used [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) for a project a few years ago and it's fairly user-friendly. It supports [many standard formats](http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Supported_Network_File_Formats.html).

More graph theory recommendations are available on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/graph-theory-software).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Graphviz/Dot wrapper, which reads .sqlite Database files from the command line:

https://gitlab.com/Screwtapello/sqlite-schema-diagram

and here is the [discussion on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39798115) (March 2024, ~80 messages) where various similar tools and attempts were mentioned by participants.