# Tool for drawing/working on graph db schemes (specifically, for neo4j)

Tags: database, graphs

I have found in several neo4j tutorials that they use the "arrow tool" (http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/) to rapidly sketch graph-database schemes.

That tool is really convenient, easy to use, etc. However it only allows you to have a working scheme –you can download your scheme in various formats but not upload it. If you I want to sketch a new scheme you must forget about editing the previous one anymore (or use different browser/computer)

So I was wondering whether there is an alternative to it. To reproduce what that tool does, essentially all that is needed is drawing/displaying nodes and relations showing for both of them their properties. See an example below:

[image: graph db scheme with arrowtool]

Comment: Graphviz - Google it :-)

Comment: @Mawg Is there a GUI to Graphviz? I really recommend to try the link above to see how rapidly can it be used to produce sketches in a WYSIWYG manner. I mean, I know I could use LaTex, for instance to generate something similar to the graph above, but it will take 5x the time and won't be interactive.

Comment: Sorry I don’t have time to give more details (I ma moving to a new project today and things are hectic), but there are plenty of Graphviz questions here (like [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52379/erd-generator-from-plain-text/52392#52392)).  Why I like Graphviz is that it takes ascii input. I generate that (from debug trace logs, etc) using Python scripts.

Comment: As for a GIU – maybe, maybe not – there is a [MS Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EFanZh.graphviz-preview) where you typ in the asci text and see the diagram being drawn as you do so. Would that help?